# How can I tell clang-format to follow this convention?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I would like to have this:

```
if (!enabled)
{
    return;
}
```

turned to this:

```
if (!enabled) { return; }
```

(In other words, I want short if-statements on a single line but keep the `{}` around them)

Currently I'm using the following configuration:

```
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
```

However, the output I'm getting is:

```
if (!enabled) 
{
    return;
}
```

Is the above formatting possible to accomplish with clang-format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing

> BreakBeforeBraces: Allman

Seems to do what you want (for me). I'm using SVN clang though.
Although you probably wanted it there for a reason.

According to the clang-format docs, the `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` should do exactly what you want (regardless of brace style). This might be a bug in clang-format.